# Different Form Submit Actions for Different Forms

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Super basic javascript question incoming...

I have two forms, one for uploading a file and one for providing text. I want to have a unique submit action for each of these forms. For the former, to upload the file, and for the latter, to serialize the form into JSON and POST it.

To attempt to accomplish this, I have one function called `submit` and another called `submit2`. The file upload form, which invokes `submit` works just fine.

The problem is with the second form, which invokes `submit2`. In particular, when I load the page, I get the following errors:

`Query.Deferred exception: undefined is not a function (near '...$('form').submit2...')`.

`TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$('form').submit2...')`

Here's my HTML.

```
Upload an image
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
    <input id="img" name="file" type="file" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Paste a URL
<form method="POST" name="urlForm" onclick="submit2()">
    <input id="imgurl" name="url" type="text">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here's my javascript.

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(form){
    var array = jQuery(form).serializeArray();
    var json = {};
    console.log(array)

    jQuery.each(array, function() {
        json[this.name] = this.value || '';
    });

    return json;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $status = $('.status');

    $('#img').change(function (event) {
        var obj = $(this)[0];
        console.log(obj)

        $status.html('');

        if (obj.files && obj.files[0]) {
            console.log(obj.files)
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                $('.img-area').html(
                    `<img class='loaded-img' src='${event.target.result}' style="width:500px;height:500px;"/>`
                );
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(obj.files[0]);
        }
    });

    $('#imgurl').change(function (event) {
        var obj = $('#imgurl').val()
        console.log(obj)
        $('.img-area').html(
            `<img class='loaded-img' src='${obj}' style="width:500px;height:500px;"/>`
        );
    });

    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var imageData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        console.log(imageData)

        $status.html(
            `<span class='eval'>Evaluating...</span>`
        );

        $.ajax({
            url: 'some_api_endpoint',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: imageData,

            success: function (responseData) {
                console.log(responseData)
                if (responseData.error != null) {
                    $status.html(
                        `<span class='result failure'>Failed</span>`
                    );
                } else {
                    $status.html(
                        `<span class='result success'>${responseData.message}</span>`
                    );
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $status.html(
                    `<span class='eval'>Something went wrong, try again later.</span>`
                );
            }
        });
    });

    $('form').submit2(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var json = ConvertFormToJSON($('form'))
        console.log(json)

        $status.html(
            `<span class='eval'>Evaluating...</span>`
        );

        $.ajax({
            url: 'some_api_endpoint',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(json),

            success: function (responseData) {
                console.log(responseData)
                if (responseData.error != null) {
                    $status.html(
                        `<span class='result failure'>Failed</span>`
                    );
                } else {
                    $status.html(
                        `<span class='result success'>${responseData.message}</span>`
                    );
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $status.html(
                    `<span class='eval'>Something went wrong, try again later.</span>`
                );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Edit: Added the `ConvertFormToJSON` function for completeness, although I think that's orthogonal to the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Note that `$(this)[0]` is exactly the same as just plain `this`

Comment: also you seem to be assuming a relationship between the "onclick" attribute and jQuery that does not in fact exist.

Comment: Where you declare ConvertFormToJSON function in your source code? Because I dont found this function in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in there Jquery Object dont have submit2 method and when you want to access submit2 method this is return undefined and when call this is return undefined is not function.